# Passing Data from Custom UIView to Main VC

Tags: swift, swift3, uiimageview, uiimage, parameter-passing

I am attempting to transfer data from my Custom UI View to my MainVC.

In my custom view (which is part of my MainVC) I have a collection of photos & if someone has selected that they wanted the photo, It should close the custom view, & make that photo appear in the MainVC. Unfortunately, I am unable to make the photo appear in the MainVC. How would I go about doing this?

In my custom UIView I have the following:

- Within the DidSelectCell

  ```
  selectedPhotoImage = mediaArray[indexPath.row].image!
  ```
- When A person chooses that they want that photo to be the one they wish to upload.

  ```
  func chooseScene(gestureRecognizer2: UIGestureRecognizer) {
      let swag = RegisterVC()
      swag.profilePhototoUpload.image = selectedPhotoImage

  }
  ```

Within the mainVC (which is the RegisterVC) I have the following:

```
 let profilePhotoSelction = UIView()
 let profilePhototoUpload = UIImageView()
 profilePhotoSelction.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 17, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 5.2, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 3.4, height: self.view.frame.size.width / 3.4)

        profilePhototoUpload.frame = profilePhotoSelction.bounds
        profilePhototoUpload.clipsToBounds = true
        profilePhototoUpload.layer.cornerRadius = profilePhototoUpload.layer.frame.width / 2


        profilePhotoSelction.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        profilePhotoSelction.layer.borderWidth = 2
        profilePhotoSelction.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(fromHex: 0xa3f323).cgColor
        profilePhotoSelction.layer.cornerRadius = profilePhotoSelction.layer.frame.width / 2


        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RegisterVC.uploadPhoto(gestureRecognizer:)))
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        profilePhotoSelction.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

        profilePhotoSelction.addSubview(profilePhototoUpload)
        self.view.addSubview(profilePhotoSelction)
```

How can I possibly get the profilePhototoUpload view have the photo that person has chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably to create a simple `protocol` that your `RegisterVC` will conform to, and when it's time to pass that image back to the `RegisterVC` you can use a protocol method.

As a very simple example, you could define your `protocol` like this:

```
protocol SelectImageDelegate {
    func didSelectImage(image: UIImage)
}
```

Then, in your custom UIView you'd need a variable for this delegate like:

```
let delegate: SelectImageDelegate
```

You'd need to add this property to your `init` so that you can set `RegisterVC` as the `delegate` during `init`.

Then, in `RegisterVC` you can add to the class declaration to conform to the protocol, so it'd look like `class RegisterVC: UIViewController, SelectImageDelegate {...`

Finally, you'll need to implement the protocol method, and do something like this:

```
func didSelectImage(image: UIImage) {
    self.profilePhotoToUpload.image = image
    //Do whatever else you need with the image here...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that seem a bit overkill for that? Since the UIView is just a subclass of the UIViewController? Also I'm trying to use this UIView in multiple areas of my application. So how would I go about setting the delegate for multiple classes using it? Instead of just solely RegisterVC

Comment: The "I'm using this in multiple areas" argument is the exact reason this is not an overkill solution.  If you make this `protocol` you can have all of your various viewControllers conform, and they can all do something different with that `didSelectImage` method.

Comment: Very interesting; I'll take a look into it; Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by this way:

1). In your custom UIView define variable of MainVC type

```
var mainVC: MainVC?
```

2). From MainVC when you open your custom UIView set its newly created `mainVC` to `self`.

3). In this view controller add method to show images, i.e

```
func showSelectedImage(image: UIImage) {
....
}
```

4). Now from custom UIView controller when the image have been selected and you are going to close the custom UIView call that method from MainVC as follows:

```
self.showSelectedImage(image:theSelectedImage)
```

This is one of approaches to solve your issue, of course you can also use protocol's.